# Forcing cmp_deep to display all differences in hash on failure

Tags: perl, testing, hash, compare

I'm writing a test in Perl, and I need to compare two big hashes.
I use `cmp_deep` ([Test::Deep](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aDeep)) and `is_deeply` ([Test::More](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMore)).
My problem is when something is different in those hashes, the program quits in the middle.

```
my $this = {    a=>1,   b=>2,   d=>2, };

my $that = {    a=>1,   b=>3,   c=>3, };

is_deeply($this , $that );
```

and the output is:

```
# not ok 1
# Failed test at Tester.pl line 32.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->{b} = '2'
#     $expected->{b} = '3'
```

but I have more values that are different! I need to see them all.
How can I force `is_deeply` to print all the differences between the hashes rather than just the first difference between them?

Furthermore, there are some keys I need to ignore them. How can I do that?

Comment: I think it's not possible to do this with `is_deeply` and it's OK. The test is not supposed to show you what to fix, but to fail when something isn't working which is a different thing. A test can't help to make your code correct, it is helpful only to show errors. Also if you want to compare *some* values of a hash, do it explicitely.

Comment: I need it because other people are going to look at the test results. and the hashes are so big so just printing "not ok" is not enough...

Comment: In that case you could insert a command which dumps the hash if the test fails.

Comment: I think your requirements are different from those of the author of `is_deeply`.  Take a good look at the man pages on http://search.cpan.org/, but you may have to write your own code to do the job you need done, because you require information the average tester does not need.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [Test::Differences](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3A%3ADifferences)?

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own testing subroutine that can be configured (which keys to ignore f.ex.) construct new copies of the filtered input and then use [http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3A%3ADifferences](Test::Differences) as @JonathanLeffler suggested to compare the filtered hashes.

Comment: I didn't manage to write this... do you have a basic code I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation is often handy for this type of thing.

Your issue is almost the exact use case in the [Test::More](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aMore) documentation.

```
use Test::More tests => 1;

my $hash1 = { a => 1, b => 2, c => 4 }; 
my $hash2 = { a => 1, b => 3, c => 4 };

is_deeply($hash1, $hash2, 'hash are equal') or diag explain($hash1,$hash2);
```

Example output:

```
not ok 1 - hash are equal
#   Failed test 'hash are equal'
#   at test.pl line 7.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->{b} = '2'
#     $expected->{b} = '3'
# {
#   'a' => 1,
#   'b' => 2,
#   'c' => 4
# }
# {
#   'a' => 1,
#   'b' => 3,
#   'c' => 4
# }
1..1
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
```

---

Sorry I initially misread your question. Carefully reading the question is very helpful in providing a proper answer. Anyhow, finding the differences in hashes can become quite complex. I believe there are several CPAN modules out there to help you with this. I'd suggest finding on there that can handle the data structure you are dealing with to compare hash differences.

Past that, I'm not aware of a good way for making Test::More or Test::Deep do what you want. Someone else will have to come along hopefully! good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As Jonathan Leffler pointed out, the best way to display all the differences is to use [Test::Differences](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Differences) and its `eq_or_diff` method.

But you probably want to keep Test::Deep because of its special features like `ignore()` and `re()`

So, use both of them. You only need to see the differences when it fails. Example code:

```
is_deeply($this, $that, "the data matches" )
    || eq_or_diff($this, $that, "the data matches (with details)");
```